# Using query results with joined parameters without anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Adapting from [this C# MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) I'm using the following statement to return a specific user to the view

```
User user = db.Users.Find(id);

if (user == null){return HttpNotFound();}
return View(user);
```

---

The `Users` model has a foreign key to `Auctions` so the view can iterate over a list of auctions associated with this user.

`Auctions` has a field called `buyerID` which corresponds with `User.ID` so I want to display the buyers name by linking back to `User.userName` by way of the `Auctions.buyerID`.

I can do this in SQL statements and LINQ as well but I think there is a simpler way.

**How can I use, `User user = db.Users.Find(id);` and join it to `User` from the foreign key of `Auctions.buyerID`?**

---

This is kind of what I thought would work but I can't create a new parameter 'buyerName' when User doesn't have this.

```
IEnumerable<User> thisUser = from usr in db.Users
       join auct in db.Auctions on usr.ID equals auct.UserID
       join ur in db.Users on auct.buyerID equals ur.ID
       where usr.ID == id
       select new User
       {
           buyerName = ur.userName
       };
```

From other posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410073/linq-anonymous-types-mvc-views-help) I read about setting up a new class but that doesn't seem to stick to the DRY & KISS principles since now I need to have two classes that vary by one parameter located in different locations.

Is there a simpler way to join the table and get the strong typing without creating a new class?

So the result should display the buyers name instead of the buyers ID#

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to avoid using anonymous type and I didn't want to create a new class I found a work around by passing a dictionary of user names to the view.

Controller

```
User user = db.Users.Find(id);

var dict = db.Users.Select(t => new { t.ID, t.userName })
           .ToDictionary(t => t.ID, t => t.userName);

ViewData["userDict"] = dict;
```

---

Now I just looked up the username based on the buyer ID

View

```
@{Dictionary<int, String> userList = ViewData["userDict"] as Dictionary<int, String>;}

@{
  if (item.buyerID.HasValue)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userList[item.buyerID.Value])
  }
}
```